# How do I forward an X11 window as a webpage?

Tags: networking, x11

Is there any way to view an X11 window over a network, but as a webpage? I would like to run some applications off of a simple linux server and interact with them through a web browser. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You might investigate guacamole: https://guacamole.incubator.apache.org/  .  I don't know if it can interact with a single X11 window, but it does provide a web (html5) interface to remote desktop clients (VNC).

Comment: Thanks. Neither was exactly what I was looking for, but I spent a few hours figuring out Guacamole, and it's actually really cool.

Comment: I know its late, but checkout xpra as an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer you are looking for is in another thread:
[HTML client for X11 ssh forwarding?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104290/html-client-for-x11-ssh-forwarding)

TL;DR: "export your current session with x11vnc and then view it with a web based VNC viewer"